.NET Core : custom attribute "PermissionChecker" error
In my controller, I use an attribute PermissionChecker:
[HttpGet]
[PermissionChecker(Permission = "F8B5660F-60A4-48EC-BFFC-9DC0CCD88FA6")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetuserList()
{
   try
   {
       return Ok(await _userService.getuserList(request));
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
   }
}

PermissionChecker:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using SurgeryRoomScheduler.Application.Services.Implementations;
using SurgeryRoomScheduler.Application.Services.Interfaces;
using SurgeryRoomScheduler.Domain.Entities.Account;
using SurgeryRoomScheduler.Domain.Interfaces;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SurgeryRoomScheduler.Application.Utilities
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class PermissionCheckerAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public string Permission { get; set; }
        private readonly IUserService _userService;

        public PermissionCheckerAttribute(IUserService userService)
        {
            _userService = userService;
        }

        public override async void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            var user = context.HttpContext.User;

            if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult(); // Return a 401 Unauthorized response
                return;
            }

            var userRole = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)?.Value;

            if (userRole == null || !Guid.TryParse(userRole, out var userRoleId))
            {
                context.Result = new ForbidResult(); // Return a 403 Forbidden response
                return;
            }

            bool hasPermission = await _userService.CheckUserHavePermission(Guid.Parse(userRole), Guid.Parse(Permission));

            if (!hasPermission)
            {
                context.Result = new ForbidResult(); // Return a 403 Forbidden response
                return;
            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(context);
        }
    }
}

I have a problem I need to use _userService, so I injected it into this class.
But I got an error from this line of code:
[PermissionChecker(Permission = "F8B5660F-60A4-48EC-BFFC-9DC0CCD88FA6")]

Error is:

Error CS7036
There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter 'userService' of 'PermissionCheckerAttribute.PermissionCheckerAttribute(IUserService)'  SurgeryRoomScheduler.Presentation   D:\MiladProjects\SurgeryRoomScheduler\SurgeryRoomScheduler.Presentation\Controllers\UserSide\AccountController.cs   40  Active

I try to add user service as input parameter of the attribute, but that did not work

The compilation error occurs because attributes cannot take dependencies via constructor injection, you can retrieve the service from somewhere else.
Define another service grabber
ServiceGrabber.cs
public static class ServiceGrabber
{
    private static IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public static void Configure(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public static T GetService<T>()
    {
        return _serviceProvider.GetService<T>();
    }
}

Register it in your program.cs
ServiceGrabber.Configure(app.Services);
app.Run();

Then there is no need to set it in your ActionFilterAttribute.
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class PermissionCheckerAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string Permission { get; set; }

    public PermissionCheckerAttribute()
    {
    }

    public override async void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var userService = ServiceGrabber.GetService<IUserService>();
        ...
    }
    ...
}


An attribute are a method to describe information about a specific part of your code, in this case a method. The attribute in itself should not handle your authentication - as said it should be a method to describe (on other words) "tag" information.
Also attributes can not be instantiated with injected dependencies, but however Filters can. In your case based upon IAuthorizationFilter. This filter should be registered in your StartUp.
Below is example code, your filter:
public class PermissionRequirementFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    readonly Permissions _permission;
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public PermissionRequirementFilter(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    public PermissionRequirementFilter(Permissions permission, IUserService userService)
    {
        _permission = permission; // This is where you receive your attribute!
        _userService = userService;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
         var user = context.HttpContext.User;

        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult(); // Return a 401 Unauthorized response
            return;
        }

        var userRole = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role)?.Value;

        if (userRole == null || !Guid.TryParse(userRole, out var userRoleId))
        {
            context.Result = new ForbidResult(); // Return a 403 Forbidden response
            return;
        }

        bool hasPermission = await _userService.CheckUserHavePermission(Guid.Parse(userRole), Guid.Parse(Permission));

        if (!hasPermission)
        {
            context.Result = new ForbidResult(); // Return a 403 Forbidden response
            return;
        }
        
         base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}

And this is the attribute:
 public class PermissionRequirementAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
    {
        public PermissionRequirementAttribute(string permission) : base(typeof(PermissionRequirementFilter))
        {
            Arguments = new object[] { permission };
        }
    }

Again: you need to register your Filter in the StartUp
